# Script out hierarchy of macros

Tags: ms-access, macros

I am attempting to document the hierarchical logic of macros within an MS Access database to allow expedited review and subsequent reference for development. I know there are addons that can be purchased to do the same, but is there an option within access 2016 so as to view the data in a tree form, with nodes and branches, instead of having to do this manually?

Comment: Few Access applications use data macros and I doubt there would be much to document. Perhaps you not asking about macros but about Visual Basic Code for Applications (VBA). Also more confusing is you state "view the data in a tree form". Are you talking about VBA code, or data being viewed here? Been in this industry for a VERY long time and ever heard of application code being called "data".  If you did mean to view code in a tree like view, then no built in tool exists. However, not even Visual Studio has that ability. Perhaps you post a screen shot of the type of tool you talking about?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Your note: "If you did mean to view code in a tree like view, then no built in tool exists....", is what I intended to say. I know in SQL server, a logic tree of procedures called/tables accessed can be created. But if nothing like that exists in Access, I may simply recreate in SQL Server and go on from there.

Comment: Well if you talking about a query plan, that is SPECULATOR AND MASSIVE different kind of request on your part. The access database engine can produce a query plan (like SQL server can, but in the case of Access (or SQL server) the query plan is NEVER used for documentation nor does SQL server produce some tree view of the t-sql code used nor does it display how any t-sql procedure code or functions are related. So we still at some imaginary spaghetti monster in terms of your request and what tool(s) you are attempting to use for a comparison here.

Comment: There is nothing in the SQL suite of tools that in any way shows relationships between bits and parts of code written in t-sql. So if one t-sql routine calls several others, there is no built in tools that will show this type of relationships in that code.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I think starting with a query plan in MS Access would be a good start.

Comment: How on earth is creating a query plan for one query executed going to help much of anything in terms of documenting VBA code which you admit you looking for? A query will often produce DIFFERENT query plans based on criteria! The query plan only helps one debug slow queries and show that a “bad” plan was created (eg: full table scan vs index used to retrieve the given results). Simple change in criteria will change the query plan. Never heard of query plans being used to document application code. Query plans are VERY separate from your VBA, or c++ or C# or whatever coding system you are using

Comment: If you looking for query plans, then check out showplan as noted in this article: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/